# Get WooCommerce Variable Product attribute selected value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I have two attributes in my woocommerce single product page that I have added, "Metal" and "Ring Size". They are "variations" such that they are drop down selections on my product page.

I want to be able to on click of my button, I can be able to ***grab the selected value*** and put it onto my URL parameter.

I solved everything up to the part where the value that is grabbed isn't correct.

I have so far tried this but it is just giving me a list of this attributes possible values/selections and not the single selected value..

```
$metal = $product->get_attribute( 'Metal' );

http://example.com/?metal=18K%20White%20Gold%20|%2018K%20Yellow%20Gold%20|%20Rose%20Gold%20|%20Platinum
```

I just want what I selected on the drop down, something like this:

```
http://example.com/?metal=Platinum
```

Comment: Using your code from before, I just want to do it through php since its all together...Im not sure what to do since I was thinking that the value selected on dropdown will be saved or into the "server" once you hit the "make appointment button". Is there a way to "echo" drop down buttons? so i can work this in php? But I guess its pretty difficult because the selections need to change Image & Price responsively...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of code that may be you will need to customize a little bit. This code will:

- display temporary custom button (for testing purpose) with a custom href value like:
   `home-url/?metal=` … *(`home-url` is your website url)*
- get the selected value from  your "metal" attribute and will append it to the button URL.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'get_variation_selectected_value', 25 );
function get_variation_selectected_value() {
    global $product;

    // Display button (Just for testing purpose) 
    // You can remove or comment the line of code below …
    // But you need to set your url like: http://example.com/?metal=
    echo '<br /><a href="'.home_url("/?metal=").'" class="book-now button">'. __('Make an Appointment Now') .'</a>';

    // The script
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Get the default value
        var selectedValue = $('select#metal option:checked').val(),
            hrefAttribute = $('a.book-now').attr("href");
            $('a.book-now').attr("href", hrefAttribute+selectedValue);

        // Display on browser console (for test)
        console.log($('a.book-now').attr("href"));

        // Get the live selected value
        $('select#metal').blur( function(){
            selectedValue = $('select#metal option:checked').val();
            hrefAttribute = $('a.book-now').attr("href");
            $('a.book-now').attr("href", hrefAttribute+selectedValue);

            // Display on browser console (for test)
            console.log($('a.book-now').attr("href"));
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code has been tested (with another attribute) and just works.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! If i were to add the Ring Size drop down as well to the URL, what would it be? I tried just changing to this, and it doesnt work. Is it because "Ring Size" is typed wrong (space)?$('select#ring_size').blur( function(){
            selectedValue = $('select#ring_size option:checked').val();
            hrefAttribute = $('a.book-now').attr("href");
            $('a.book-now').attr("href", hrefAttribute+'&ring='+selectedValue);
        });

Comment: I found it, its "ring-size". So now I tried doing it myself - cause I want http://example.com/?metal=platinum&ringsize=3. This is what I did but its giving me weird URL when I select both options "http://example.com/?metal=Platinum&ringsize=&metal=Platinum&ringsize=13"

Comment: This is what I tried --> <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('select').blur( function(){
            selectedValue = $('select#metal option:checked').val();
            ringValue = $('select#ring-size option:checked').val();
            hrefAttribute = $('a.book-now').attr("href");
            $('a.book-now').attr("href", hrefAttribute+'&metal='+selectedValue+'&ringsize='+ringValue);

        });
    });
    </script>

Comment: Live Link (ignore productsku and id) --> http://test.ascension.systems/product/ring-style1-example/?productid=1&styleid=ring-style1-example